# Check if currentUser is the user that created the Post (iOS & Parse)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to check if the `currentUser` is the same as the user that created the post in order to display a button that would let the user delete that post.

I figured the best way would be to match the `currentUser.objectId` with the Post's "user Pointer<_User>".

I'm logging the currentUser's objectId with this code:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *currentUserID = currentUser.objectId;
NSLog(@"%@", currentUserID);
```

How can I log the Post's user Pointer<_User>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to query the desired post object and then you can get the `user` pointer like retrieving the common value:

```
PFObject *post = ...; // I assume you know how to get your desired object
PFUser *postedUser = post[@"user"]; // user is the column name
```

Comment: I get this  <PFUser: 0x7f83b945d860, objectId: hd47tr75th, localId: (null)> {
}. How can I get the objectId from the PFUser to see if it matches with the currentUser's objectId?

Comment: Did you read it? The log has printed out the `objectId`. You can use this if condition to check `[postedUser.objectId isEqualToString: currentUser.objectId]`.